# Python, Azure Servicebus how to catch an exception handling?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm writing an azure function in python. After receiving a message I will forward n-messages.

My code is:

```
def sendToQueue(data):
    logging.info('sendToQueue: %s', data)  
    msg = Message(encodeData(data))
    d = json.loads(data)
    batchId = d['BatchId']
    logging.info('sending message with batch Id: %s', batchId)  
    try:
      logging.info('Sending oos message to queue %s', queue_oos_mssql_inbox)
      sbs.send_queue_message(queue_oos_mssql_inbox, msg)
      logging.info('Done Sending oos message to queue %s', queue_oos_mssql_inbox)
    except :
      logging.error('Unable to process message %s', batchId)
      errorDescription = 'Unable to sent message to ' + queue_oos_mssql_inbox
      logging.error('errorDescription message %s', errorDescription)
      error = createErrorMessage(batchId, '404', str(errorDescription))
      logging.error('error message %s', error)
      sendToErrorQueue(json.loads(error))

    logging.debug('done sending message: ')
```

When it's not able to sent the message I would like to log the error. How do I do something like this: 'except pyodbc.Error as ex:', but then with ServiceBus.error?

I can't find any samples or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is rather simple, just added

```
exception Exception as e:
    logging.error("Error msg: " + str(e))
```

.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the root error class `ServiceBusError`:

```
    try:
      logging.info('Sending oos message to queue %s', queue_oos_mssql_inbox)
      sbs.send_queue_message(queue_oos_mssql_inbox, msg)
      logging.info('Done Sending oos message to queue %s', queue_oos_mssql_inbox)
    except ServiceBusError as e:
      logging.error('Unable to process message %s', batchId)
      logging.exception('error %s', e)
```

> ServiceBusError: All other Service Bus related errors. It is the root error class of all the errors described above.

Or any other described in:

https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/

or in the reference docs:

https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-servicebus/latest/azure.servicebus.html#module-azure.servicebus.exceptions